# Show "N/A" if a variable is undefined or null or empty in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to do something like this in a PHP view file (Laravel/Blade):

```
{{ empty($candidate->current_address) ? 'N/A' : $candidate->current_address }}
```

But it's a little bit lengthy to me. Are there any better ways to do this?

Btw, this doesn't work:

```
{{ $candidate->current_address ?? 'N/A' }}
```

Because if the variable is an empty string, it just shows the empty string (not "N/A").
I also can't make a helper method because if `$candidate->current_address` is undefined, it causes Notice Error.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You mean this code works, but you want something shorter ???

Comment: You can make a helper function and use `optional($object)->$attribute`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes. I want it shorter. I need to write hundreds of this in my view files.

Comment: I'm not sure with how many class members you want to do this, but maybe you need an accessor? https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: You can write your logic there and keep the blade files clean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
{{ $candidate->current_address ?? null ?: 'N/A' }}
```

For shorter, you can write a function:

```php
function display_optional($value)
{
    return $value ?: 'N/A'
}
```

Usage:

```php
{{ display_optional($candidate->current_address ?? null) }}
```

Comment: Yes, this works and is the best answer but this could confuse my teammates. So I'll resort to some UI design change instead of using "N/A".

Comment: If you have to nest the calls like that, you should group them to make it more readable and to prevent possible side effects for the operator precedence. Something like:  `$candidate->current_address ?? (null ?: 'N/A')`

Answer (score 0):

In your candidate model, you could add:

```
function getCurrentAddressAttribute()
{
  return $this->attributes['current_address'] ?: 'N/A';
}
```

Then in blade you only need to do:

```
{{ $candidate->current_address }}
```

More info here: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

#### UPDATE:

I see you have to many values to apply this to, so the other option is:

```
{{ $candidate->current_address ?: 'N/A' }}
```

#### 3rd option:

You could also make a helper function like so:

```
function showIfAvailable($somevalue)
{
  return $somevalue ?: 'N/A';
}
```

And then use this in blade:

```
{{ showIfAvailable($candidate->current_address) }}
```

Beware that adding your own helper functions requires you to make a file(for instance App\helperFunctions.php) and then add it to composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/helperFunctions.php"
    ] 
}
```

And then run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

After these actions, you should have access to your functions in blade.

Look into: https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers for more info

Comment: Thank you but I have too many attributes to write methods for each of them...

Answer (score 0):

You could create a helper file and create a custom function, then you could do the following:

```
{{ blank_formatted($candidate->current_address) }}

{{ blank_formatted(optional($candidate->current_address)->firstname) }}
// if current_address does not exist
```

Create your new helper file `app/Http/helpers.php`

Define your function:

```
<?php

if (! function_exists('blank_formatted')) {
    /**
     * @param null $value
     *
     * @return string
     */
    function blank_formatted($value = null)
    {
        return blank($value) ? 'N/A' : $value;
    }
}
```

add it to your composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/Http/helpers.php"
    ],
},
```

run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: I think I can't pass `blank_formatted($var->undefined->attribute)`. It causes an error.

Comment: @chikaram yes then you would have to call it with optional like `optional($candidate->current_address)->firstname`, I updated my answer.